# Какой надо указать MimeType в Desktop Entry, чтобы отслеживать deb файлы

Tags: linux, shell, desktop

Какой надо указать MimeType, чтобы была возможность отслеживать .deb файлы?

Я пробовал подобную реализацию, но она не работает:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
NoDisplay=false
Hidden=false
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=file/deb;
Actions=add_in_my_prog

[Desktop Action add_in_my_prog]
Name=My tool
Name[ru]=Моя программа
Exec=/usr/bin/mprog
```

Comment: Эээ... отслеживать?

Comment: Первая ссылка в G на запрос _.deb mime-type_: `deb (file format)
Filename extension .deb
Internet media type application/vnd.debian.binary-package`